# making ASP.net responsive for mobile devices

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

We have our webpages made in ASP.net Web Forms and MVC. We would like to make them accessible for mobile devices. Does anyone has a good reference on how to accomplish this? Or any suggestions on how to make responsive webpages?

I was thinking about making 2 master pages. One for mobile and one for desktops but I think there may be a better way to do it..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should check out "Media Queries". Or possibly look into using the twitter bootstrap or another grid framework.

Comment: Thank you, I think Media Queries is what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the following approach since we have to support old browsers (Like IE7) and we don't want to transmit the markup and styles that apply to all possible devices...

This article describes how to add mobile pages to asp applications:

http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application

Answer (score 6):

What you need is something called CSS media queries. Basically you create different CSS rules for specific screen sizes.
For example

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

will set the body background to red color whenever your browser window/screen width is larger than 520px and smaller than 700px.

Try googling for 'CSS media query' and 'responsive design', that'll point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

@Slavenko has pointed you in the right direction. I would like to top it off with the fact that there are multiple frameworks built for responsive design that utilize media queries. The one I like the most is [TwitterBootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

I've been tinkering with using a CSS framework or alternative rendering with Web Forms, and it feels like a bit of a hack sitting on top of server-side controls.

Telerik recently added a set of responsive capabilities to their ASP.NET Web Forms control suite.  The demos online like very impressive.  You can find those demos at:
http://demos.telerik.com/responsive-web-design-aspnet/samples.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just make main dive width 1200px then it automatically make mobile responsibility